Losing MDC context and CorrelationToken in feign
We save the CorrelationToken request header value in the MDC context using a simple filter, then we use this value in the logback.xml to put the token into the logs so we can search for log lines relating to a request.
This works everywhere in the app except for errors logged by feign. Presumably it's doing its work on a thread which can't "see" the MDC context.
NOTE: we use Spring Boot 2.0 and Java 8.
How do we get the Correlation token into the feign thread?
This is not to do with retries, which are covered in other posts.
Filter which stores the correlationToken in MDC:
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class CorrelationFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String CORRELATION_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME = "X-CorrelationToken";
    public static final String CORRELATION_TOKEN_MDC_KEY = "correlationToken";
    public static final String CORRELATION_TOKEN_KV_MDC_KEY = "correlationTokenKV";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String correlationToken = httpRequest.getHeader(CORRELATION_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME);

        if (correlationToken == null || correlationToken.isEmpty()) {
            correlationToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }

        MDC.put(CORRELATION_TOKEN_MDC_KEY, correlationToken);
        MDC.put(CORRELATION_TOKEN_KV_MDC_KEY, "correlationToken:" + correlationToken);
        httpResponse.setHeader(CORRELATION_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME, correlationToken);

        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove(CORRELATION_TOKEN_MDC_KEY);
            MDC.remove(CORRELATION_TOKEN_KV_MDC_KEY);
        }
    }
}

Here is logback.xml:
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", UTC} %-5level %thread %logger{42} [%X{correlationTokenKV}] => %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>

Here are the dependencies in pom.xml:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Here is where we call feign:
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@EnableFeignClients
@FeignClient(value="siteserver-api", url="${client.siteserver-api}")
public interface SiteServerApi {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/ssviewer/GetSomeEvent/{eventId}?responseFormat=json", consumes = "application/json")
    public String getSomeEvent(@PathVariable("eventId") String eventId);
}

Here we see the first line is with the correlationToken, the second (logged from within feign) is without:
2024-09-27T13:08:36,252Z INFO  http-nio-8080-exec-8 c.g.s.c.MyController [correlationToken:39d9fa53-d5fa-4266-b43c-797c57ae8c85] => Save Request String :VariableRequest(selectionId=123, brand=TEST, language=en-GB)

2024-09-27T13:08:36,371Z ERROR http-nio-8080-exec-8 o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] [] => Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.RetryableException: client.siteserver-api executing GET https://xxxrOutcome/123&responseFormat=json] with root cause
java.net.UnknownHostException: xxx
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)

Similar (but not suitable) questions:

Propagation of MDC to a Feign Thread

https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1900


